# Ошибка при вызове хранимой процедуры через Entity Framework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

Добрый день

Работаю с **Oracle** базой через **Entity Framework** 5.0.0 **Database first**
создал хранимку (проверил ее на староне базы работает нормально)

Столкнулся с такой ошибкой при вызове хранимки

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:
>     PLS-00302: component 'НАЗВАНИЕХРАНИМКИ' must be declared
>     ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
>     PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, что в схеме пользователя под которым подключается Entity Framework нет объектов, совпадающих с названием схемы в которой создана хранимая процедура. Например, есть процедура создана в USER1.Proc, а запускается от имени USER2. Проверьте, что у пользователя USER2 в схеме нет объектов с именем "USER1".